# trigger('click') behaves differently to actual user click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, click

I'm trying to have a webpage perform a click of a specific button when a string is passed via the url.

```
...url?key=button1
```

HTML:

```
 <button type="submit" id="button1" value="*some other url*" >Button 1</button
```

I then have the following jquery:

```
var locate = window.location;
locate = locate.toString();
var text = locate;

$(function(){
 var temp = "?key="; 
        if (text.indexOf(temp) !== -1)
        {
        var position = text.indexOf(temp) + temp.length;
        text = text.substring (position); 
       $(window).load(function ()
            { 
                if (text == 'button1')
                {
                    $("#button1").trigger('click');
                } 
            })
        }             
   })
```

Then further in my jquery I have the following code

```
$("#button1").live("click", function() {

     $('#userform').attr('target', '_blank'); 
     $('#userform').delay(3000).queue(function()
           {
            $('#userform').attr('target', '').dequeue();
           });
});
```

Then reason I'm doing the above is outside of my control.

For privacy reasons, all I can say is that the page performs a submit, then redirects to specified page in the value of the submit button.

Right now the page behaves as you would think.

User clicks the button, form target set to '_blank', form submits some data and is redirected to the url in the value of the button. Clicking of the button opens up a new tab.

My issue, however, is that on page load with the information in the url, the click is performed of the button but instead of opening in a new tab as it normally does, it opens in a new window.

Is there any reason why doing .trigger('click') or even $("#button1").click() opens up in a new window as opposed to when the user clicks the button and it opens up in a new tab?

Comment: From what I understand, the opening of an anchor with ``target="_blank"`` is handled differently by different browsers, meaning that IE9 might open a new window, whereas chrome will probably open a tab. If this is not the behavior you are witnessing, could you please make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: isn't that what `_blank` is supposed to do?  Open a new window?

Answer (score 1):

You need to need to prevent the default behavior of the button (which is to submit to specified URL) within the function you are binding to button1 using click.)

Comment: `$("#button1").live("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `.click()` method on the element itself (ie, not the jQuery object):

```
var btn = $("#button1");
if (text == 'button1' && btn.length)
{
    btn[0].click();
}
```